# Android detection of user eye focus coordinates on screen

Tags: android, opencv

I have this issue I have to make an application that is able to detect the x,y position of where the user is looking at the application,  by that I dont mean like detecting user eye coordinates on face recognition like with opencv, I need the exact position of where the user is watching the screen, I have look everywhere and seem to find nothing on it.  a little help of where can I research more about it would be nice, right now I can only find is opencv answers related to show the coordinates of both eyes when doing some facial recognition showing the camera, but thats not what I need.

thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you gonna find anything. I think you best solution is using openCV to get the eyes coordinates and make your own parser to screen x,y position on the screen. Somebody else may have a better solution though, I just don't know it

Comment: Sounds very difficult to me.  You'd need to estimate the direction of vectors coming out of pupils.  It would vary depending on person, face angle.  I'd guess you'd need high res images.  Too bad phones don't have dual front facing cameras--you could use a stereo effect to get a better idea of depth.

Comment: yeah I was planing on getting it in stereo and each side for each eye, after a long day of research , found nothing yet.. thanks for the replies, and probably wont have the necessary time to get the direction of the eye, as you mention it is hard.. but thanks for the replies